# Is my logo good for a competition

Tags: logo, critique

A new institution, namely the Mauritius Renewable Energy Agency (MARENA) for the sustained promotion of the use of renewables for electricity generation will be set up. The institution will have the main task of creating an enabling environment for the development of renewable energy and will work closely with the International Renewable Energy Agency and the Energy Efficiency Management Office (EEMO) to promote the renewable energy agenda.

[image: first logo]

I know the font is not good. I only want to know if my symbol is good.

[image: second logo]

Comment: Will it print well?

Comment: sorry i dont understand can you please explain i wont print it and the colors is not good i just want to know if the symbol is good before i send it its for a competiton

Comment: A logo will almost certainly be used as printed. So one thing people are going to judge your logo by will it print well. I

Comment: ah ok i understand but what is your opnion for the symbol i used is it good for energy recycle

Comment: With all my respect. The logo, whatever it is, it is "weak". The "circle" white space looks squared and the white space vs. color looks not balanced. The yellow, Is it yellow, greenish yellow? The green do not look like a printable color.

Comment: i agree with you the color is not rite actually this is the real logo :
http://www.brandsoftheworld.com/critique/marena

Comment: Hi irfan, thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/682) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and please refrain from using all caps, it's considered very impolite. If you want to put emphasis on something, use Bold or Italic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should explain your logo. Instead of just submitting a logo create a logo guide which explains its colour and the design concept. You can also include mood board to show how you ended up with this.

About the logo shape: 
Try adding some depth to colours by using gradients for each colour so that it gives shaded effect. You can also use shadows of one element creating a shade on other element.

Check this link for logo trends of 2016.
http://www.creativebloq.com/infographic/rising-logo-design-trends-2016-121518161

Comment: thank you very much its my first time i am posting on this site i usually used brandsoftheworld.com thank you for your comment and the link sir

Comment: Did you buy the design from brandsoftheworld or you designed it in illustrator?

Comment: i did the logo myself